# Replace column values in a CSV file with awk

Tags: csv, text, awk, compare, zero

I have this file

error.log

> [00:00:00.284],501,
>
> [00:00:00.417],5,5294100071980
>
> [00:00:02.463],501,
>
> [00:00:05.169],501,
>
> [00:00:05.529],501,
>
> [00:00:05.730],501,

so, if the field $3 its empty i want to print "No value"

Im trying this code

```
awk '{{FS=","} if($3=="") {print $1,$2,"No value"}}'
```

But it prints

```
>[00:00:00.284] 501 No value
>[00:00:02.463] 501 No value
>[00:00:05.169] 501 No value
>[00:00:05.529] 501 No value
>[00:00:05.730] 501 No value
>[00:00:07.193] 501 No value
>[00:00:09.899] 501 No value
>[00:00:31.312] 501 No value
```

Comment: Do you REALLY have blank lines between each real data line in your input file?

Answer (score 11):

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '$1 { if ($3=="") $3="No value"; print}' in.txt
```

- Passes the field separator via the `-F` option.
- Variable `OFS`, the output-field separator, is set to `,`, so that output fields are also separated by `,`.
- Pattern `$1` ensures that only non-empty lines are processed (that is, the associated action is only executed if the first field is non-empty) - *if your input file has no empty lines, you can remove this pattern*.
- If the 3rd field is empty, it is assigned string "No value"
- Finally, the line (with the potentially modified 3rd field) is output.

The above is how I suggest you approach the problem, but here are the problems with your original command:

- `{{FS=","}...`
  Inside your single action - which due to not having a preceding pattern is executed for every input line - you set variable `FS` *for every line* - which is not only unnecessary but *too late*, because the first input line has already been parsed by that time (thanks, @EdMorton) - either set it in a `BEGIN` block (`BEGIN { FS="," }`) or, as in my answer, with command-line option `-F` (`-F ','`).
- `if($3=="") {...}`
  You only produce output if field `$3` is empty - presumably, though, you want to output *all* lines, so with this approach you'd need an `else` branch (to print unmodified lines).
- `print $1,$2,"No value"`
  The `,` chars. here are part of the syntax - they simply separate the arguments passed to `print`. Given separate arguments, `print` concatenates them with the value of the special `OFS` variable, whose value is a single *space* by default; to use `,` instead, you have to assign it to `OFS` - again, either in a `BEGIN` block or via the `-v` option (`-v OFS=','`).

Comment: `{FS=","}... [not a problem functionally, but inefficient]` IS a problem as it won't be executed until after the first line of the input file is split into fields using the defaults FS.

Comment: We can tell from the posted input that $3 can be numeric, and we know he wants to print "No value" when it's empty, but he doesn't say that it can't have the numeric value 0 so testing `!$3` is not the same as testing for "empty", that'd be `$3 == ""`.

Answer (score 3):

With this file

```
cat file
[00:00:00.284],501,
[00:00:00.417],5,5294100071980
[00:00:02.463],501,
[00:00:05.169],501,
[00:00:05.529],501,
[00:00:05.730],501,
```

This `awk` should do

```
awk -F, '$3=="" {$3="No value"}1' OFS=, file
[00:00:00.284],501,No value
[00:00:00.417],5,5294100071980
[00:00:02.463],501,No value
[00:00:05.169],501,No value
[00:00:05.529],501,No value
[00:00:05.730],501,No value
```

Comment: +1 for concision; I'm curious as to why you chose the pseudo-filename form `OFS=,` over the option form `-v OFS=,` - just typing convenience? The semantics are subtly different, though in this case they work out the same. (Also, you assume there are no blank lines - which is probably a fair assumption.)

Comment: Just to save three characters :) `-v ` no other reason.

Answer (score 2):

You should post some expected output but I THINK what you want is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF{print $1, $2, ($3=="" ? "No value" : $3)}' file
```

Comment: +1 for elegance. (The only thing to watch out for - IF generalization were needed - is that the solution is limited to 3 output columns).