# Edit CSV column with unix command

Tags: linux, csv, awk

I have a CSV table structured as below (I aligned columns for clarity):

```
AAAA, BBBB,                CCCC, DDDD
EEEE, FFFF;1111,           GGGG, HHHH
IIII, JJJJ;2222;3333;4444, KKKK, LLLL
```

And in the second column I would like to remove everything after the first occurrence of a semi-colon, resulting in:

```
AAAA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDD
EEEE, FFFF, GGGG, HHHH
IIII, JJJJ, KKKK, LLLL
```

I've tried various awk commands inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249763/how-to-edit-a-particular-column-in-csv-file-with-unix-command), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641452/replace-column-values-in-a-csv-file-with-awk), and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136322/how-to-replace-the-content-of-a-specific-column-with-awk), but can't quite get it.

I understand I could select the second column and edit it by `awk -F, '{print $2}' file | cut -d ';' -f 1`, but can't seem to figure out how to replace the second column with that command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{sub(";[^,]+","")}1' file
```

or, perhaps better

```
$ sed -E 's/;[^,]+//' file
```